# Properly formatting Ember custom serializer response for sideloaded JSON API data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to try serving [sideloaded data](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/models/customizing-serializers/) to my Ember app. I have a `city` model which `hasMany` `fireStations`. I changed my `hasMany` relationship to have an `{ async: false }` option to coincide with sideloading, since the data will no longer be loaded asynchronously.

I use a custom serializer, and I am logging the response from `normalize()`. It looks like this for my data.

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "3",
    "type": "city",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "Anytown USA"
    },
    "relationships": {
      "fireStations": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "17",
            "type": "fire-station"
          },
          {
            "id": "18",
            "type": "fire-station"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "included": [
    {
      "id": "17",
      "type": "fire-station",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "North Side Fire Station"
      },
      "relationships": {}
    },
    {
      "id": "18",
      "type": "fire-station",
      "attributes": {
        "name": "East Side Fire Station"
      },
      "relationships": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

I *think* my sideloaded data is properly formatted. It seems to match the [example in the guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.17.0/models/customizing-serializers/#toc_sideloaded-data). The `included` array is populated with all my sideloaded data, and it all seems to be formatted as needed.

However, I'm hitting this error in my app.

> Assertion Failed: You looked up the 'fireStations' relationship on a 'city' with id 3 but some of the associated records were not loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the parent record, or specify that the relationship is async ('DS.hasMany({ async: true })')

According to the JSON API spec, the format I am using seems to be correct for loading [compound documents](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-compound-documents).

> In a compound document, all included resources MUST be represented as an array of resource objects in a top-level `included` member.

And it seems [links](http://jsonapi.org/format/#document-resource-object-links) are optional, so it should be fine that I am leaving them out.

> The optional `links` member within each resource object contains links related to the resource.

I can't figure out what the issue is here. I forked [ember-data](https://github.com/emberjs/data) locally and I do indeed see [this assertion is triggered](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/addon/-private/system/relationships/state/has-many.js#L270).

If I manually loop over the `manyArray` in `has-many.js`, I see that each record is marked as `isEmpty` being `true`

Why are the `has-many` records returning `isEmpty === true`? What might I be doing wrong that is preventing sideloading from working correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create an [Ember Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/bf8c3df8495456c2b13280c3a007661d?openFiles=serializers.city.js%2C) to find, recreate, and resolve my issue.

Short answer is that my custom serializer was dropping `included` during normalization. I was confusing the responsibilities between [normalize()](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer/methods/normalize?anchor=normalize) and [normalizeResponse()](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer/methods/normalize?anchor=normalizeResponse) and returning `included` from the wrong method.

I was trying to set the `included` property on the hash in `normalize()` (that's what you see in my question above). This approach was entirely wrong.

`included` should be present in the response from `normalizeResponse()`, if needed. So I (superfluously) had `included` in `response()`, but didn't have it where it was actually needed in `normalizeResponse()`.

```
normalizeResponse (store, primaryModelClass, payload, id, requestType) {
  let { data, included } = this._super(...arguments);

  // Do some manipulation on `data` or `included`.

  // Oh no! We lost the `included` array!
  // This will cause an error
  // because we are saying the
  // relationship is not async, but we're
  // dropping the `included` data!
  return { data };

  // This is what we want, for this contrived example.
  // return { data, included };
}
```

If an `included` array needs to be returned, it should be returned from `normalizeResponse()`, not `normalize()`. This should be obvious to anyone looking at the source code for the [JSONAPISerializer in `json-api.js`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.17.0/addon/serializers/json-api.js#L139), but I somehow got lost along the way.

In [the JSONAPISerializer implementation for ember-data 2.17.0](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v2.17.0/addon/serializers/json-api.js#L139), you can see that `included` is set on the `documentHash` in a method invoked by `normalizeResponse()`.

My serializer does a *lot* of customization since my API is very non-standard, and I misunderstood some of the details here. Also, I think it's a bit difficult to understand what should and shouldn't be done in [each of the various `normalize...` API hooks](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember-data/2.16/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer/methods/normalize?anchor=normalizeResponse), despite the docs. Though, I think if I spent more time reading them, I probably would've understood this.